# Repartitioning dataframe from Spark limit() function

Tags: apache-spark, time, pyspark

I need to use the `limit` function to get n entries/rows from a dataframe. I do know it's not advisable, but this is meant as a pre-processing step which will not be required when actually implementing the code. However, I've read elsewhere that the resulting dataframe from using the limit function has only 1 partition.

I want to measure the processing time for my job which should not be limited by this. I actually tried repartitioning but the performance improvement is minimal (if any at all). I checked the partitioning by printing out `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()` and it's still `1`. Is there someway to force repartitioning to happen?

EDIT: Note that the `getNumPartitions()` was run after a `count` action.

EDIT2: Sample code

```
df = random_data.groupBy("col").count().sort(F.desc("count")).limit(100).repartition(10)
df.count()
print("No. of partitions: {0}".format(df.rdd.getNumPartitions())) # Prints 1
```

Comment: I'm using spark 2.2 and I'm able to re-partition the data after `limit`. Could you share the sample code?

Comment: @AyushVatsyayan: Hi, I've updated my question with the sample code.

Comment: what is the output of `df.count()` on second line

Comment: @AyushVatsyayan: I did not print out the output for `count()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `cache()` then `count()` worked.

I think Spark's lazy evaluation is not executing the repartition for some reason, but I'm not sure why since `count` is supposed to be an action.